# Traefik HTTP redirect to HTTPS

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, traefik-middleware

I've setup a traefik webrouter and redirected TCP80 and TCP443 to it as default. EntryPoints in traefik.toml are web and websecure as you can see here:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.websecure]
    address = ":443"

[certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme]
  email = "XXXX"
  storage = "/etc/traefik/acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "web"

[providers.file]
  filename = "/etc/traefik/traefik_dynamic.toml"
```

Now i tried to implement a rule which listens on HTTP and HTTPS and if clients connect to HTTP it redirects to HTTPS in default. That ist this configuration in traefik_dynamic.toml

```
[http]
  [http.routers]
    [http.routers.npm]
      entryPoints = ["web"]
      service = "npm"
      rule = "Host(`npm.XXX.de`)"
      middlewares = ["httpsRedirect"]
    [http.routers.npm-secure]
      entryPoints = ["websecure"]
      service = "npm"
      rule = "Host(`npm.XXX.de`)"
      [http.routers.npm.tls]
        certResolver = "letsencrypt"

  [http.services]
    [http.services.npm]
      [http.services.npm.loadBalancer]
        [[http.services.npm.loadBalancer.servers]]
          url = "http://192.168.1.79/"

  [http.middlewares.httpsRedirect.redirectScheme]
    scheme = "https"
    permanent = "true"
```

But that returns 404 and doesnt work. I already got it working with HTTPS OR HTTP only. But not both (unfortunately i deleted the working HTTPS and HTTP config; stupid me). What would be the correct way to implement a HTTP to HTTPS redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Here's two solutions, one that I have on my server and a new one from traefik documentation.

### First option

The following should work (modified from yaml syntax so take it with a grain of salt):

```
    [http.routers.redirecttohttps]:
      [http.routers.redirecttohttps.entryPoints]:
        - web

      [http.routers.redirecttohttps.middlewares]:
        - httpsredirect

      rule: 'HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)'
      service: noop
```

It creates a no-operation service for each hostname (modify the regexp if you don't want it for all) and adds the redirect middleware to them.

### Second option

Since [Traefik documentation](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.2/routing/entrypoints/#redirection) these days recommends this, I think this  is the better solution:

```
  [entryPoints.web.http]
    [entryPoints.web.http.redirections]
      [entryPoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint]
        to = "websecure"
        scheme = "https"
```

It even seems so straightforward that no explanation is needed.